# How to avoid maintaining database context over long periods with the repository pattern (And is this even a sensible Architecture?)

Tags: architecture, repository

I'm trying to build a 'distributed' data system. My first attempt is built using Entity Framework.

Very loosely, it's built around having `Element` objects, which themselves have a group of `Property` objects. Much like class objects and their properties.

The reason is that any changes to these are synchronized between the distributed modules with a messaging system.

So, say I've got a little service that reads some hardware. It has the "Fridge" `Element` with the `Property` "Temperature". If this `Property` value changes, it's set like this:

```
TemperatureProperty.Value = 1234;
```

the messaging system picks that up, and if the property has the flag `IsStream`, submits a message and all the other modules receive the update and fire an OnValueChanged event. (It also prevents this from being written to the database).

So the user interface, on a different computer, has it's temperature property receive a message, update and fire off the event. The UX knows about the change and can display the new value.

Similarly, other changes that are less common, but also need a reaction (say a new `Element`), a "Configuration" change request is sent out. This just tells the recipient that the object they have is out of date.

I'm using a central Repository. The whenever an object is requested from the repository (or lazy loaded) it wires up any relevant events. Streamed values are immediately dispatched over the message system, other changes are tracked and propagated with the OnSave method:

[image]

My whole ethos was making the API as easy as possible. You don't have to know there's a message service, or whether this property is streaming, sending out configuration changes, or anything if you don't need to.

You just care that you've got a Temperature property, and it has a new value, so you set it. Or the values has changed, so you do something. Everything else is maintain managed by the 'framework'.

However, this results in a very long-lasting DBContext. The entity framework is always 'active'. This is really nice to work with, as lazy loading makes things work really well.

But I'm reading more and more that the DBContext should be short-lived, and certainly not kept 'online' for application-length time-spans.

With these little hardware services, the DBContext would be sitting there 24/7 to keep things up to date.

I also tried to create my lovely "just use it like any other thing" `Property` in a test service - except I did the hardware reading in a Task (so on a different thread. Well, of course, all hell broke lose because DBContext isn't thread safe.

Does anyone have any advice on how to maintain the features, the on-save change tracking, but incorporating the "Unit of Work" type structure?

Or should I re-think the whole architecture and try move away from the repository pattern?

Comment: So what prevents you from making the DBContext short-lived?

Comment: Well, it would break lazy-loading (so effectively property relationships, unless explicitly loaded), and while it would make the API more verbose (Instead of getting the related item you'd have to always get entities directly from the repository) it would completely break the OnSave functionality.

Comment: So, it would be possible, but instead of getting an Element and using it, you do Repository.GetElement(id), then Repository.GetProperty(id) and instead of just using the objects and them being up to date, you'd have to all Repository.UpdateElement(newElement) and UpdateProperty etc etc. But you don't need to call UpdateProperty if it's a stream property.

Kind of defeats the point of using Entity Framework at all, because I get none of the advantages of it. Might as well just wrap a few queries?

Comment: I could wrap the Entity Framework objects in a more fleshed-out object and kind of perform my own lazy loading? That seems like a really bad idea though.

Comment: `Might as well just wrap a few queries?`  -- Not a bad idea here.  Using ADO, ExecuteQuery or a micro-ORM like Dapper might all be better solutions than EF.

Comment: I'll certainly co sider it and having a slightly more verbose API that i have more control over. (Maybe i could make it immutable, that would solve a lot of issues)

Comment: I wonder whether using a redux type store might be the way to go.

Comment: Personally, I don't like repositories in general, but not for these reasons. Because they tend to be a storage location for global data with all the consequences that entails. The main problem I see with your design is the granularity is too fine (message per property change), and the serialization of property changes is not separate from the property change itself. You could keep a copy of the original property values, periodically check that against current values, and send out all changes in a batch.

Comment: High granularity is an aim, as I want as close to real time updates as possible. So there might be something listening to the temperature of x and switching a device when a threshold is reached. This is only with values specifically on a "stream" property. All other changes only send out updates when the DBContext 'save changes" method is called and i hook into EFs change tracking to send out a bulk update message.

Comment: A global store is something that concerns me too, it's also an issue with the redux type implementation. I'm not if it would be possible tracking and updating all these objects without some kind of global state though.